# Flutter java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

Every time I build and run my Flutter app, I get this error message:

```
Exception thrown while unbinding
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzjp@9f10cc9
    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1044)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1337)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:616)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:55)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.unbindService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:50)
    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zziv.zzag(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.5.0:245)
    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zziv.zzal(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.5.0:262)
    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zziv.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.5.0:336)
    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zziu.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.5.0:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzai.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.5.0:7)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfy.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.5.0:21)
```

App doesn't crash, but I'd like to understand what's going on.I'm using firebase_core, firebase_auth and cloud_firestore. I spent some time researching, but didn't succeed to find an explanation.

Comment: Are you using the plugin admob_flutter by chance?

Comment: same issue. I'm using a firebase_admob plugin. Any solution?

Comment: have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1662)

Comment: Adding `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.5.0'` to `android/app/build.gradle` dependencies solved this problem for me.

Comment: @J.Saw Yes i am and also got this issue. have you fixed this?

Comment: @BasilMariano actually no, I never fixed it. I couldn't figure out where the error was coming from, but I narrowed it down to admob_flutter. I have since released at least one app with it and no issues are present. I'll check again shortly on the latest version and see if that error still occurs.

Comment: Have you found the solution yet bro.!
I would believe that is because of the FireBase Notifications and it only happens in the new Version of Flutter right